# How to adjust modal height?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I have a problem opening the modal page using a device. The problem is that it is filling the page rather than popping up. What might be the problem? The modal is popping up in the web browser but it open on the device, but it fills the page. How can I solve this aspect. Best Regards

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Network, Toast} from "ionic-native";
import {ModalPagePage} from '../modal-page/modal-page';
import {NavController, Platform,ModalController} from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  public people: Array<Object>;
  onDevice: boolean;


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public modalCtrl: ModalController) {


    this.platform.ready().then(() => {

      this.onDevice = this.platform.is('cordova');



    });

  }




  presentProfileModal() {
    let profileModal = this.modalCtrl.create(ModalPagePage);

    profileModal.present();
  }




}
```

Comment: The modal presentation is set in CSS, so you need to paste relevant HTML and CSS if you want us to help.

Comment: I think Ionic did this on purpose, because it is good UX to let the modal have the whole screen on smaller devices.

Comment: @codeepic  modal-page.scss is:                                                                          page-modal-page {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;

}                                                                                                           }
Modal-page.html is:                                                                                 <ion-header>

  <ion-title primary>My custom modal</ion-title>
  <ion-buttons end>
    <button (click)="dismiss()">Close</button>
  </ion-buttons>

</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>

</ion-content>

Answer (score 0):

```
.modal-wrapper {
    position: absolute !important;
    width: 93vw !important;
    height: 260px !important;
    top: 0 !important;
    bottom: 0 !important;
    left: 0 !important;
    right: 0 !important;
    margin: auto !important;
}

.modal .backdrop {
    display: block !important;
}
```

Over ride modal's default CSS in variable.scss.